# Degree of the extension $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})/\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ is at most 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

In chapter 13 of Dummit and Foote, there is the following example:

*Consider the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ generated over $\mathbb{Q}$ by $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$.  Since $\sqrt{3}$ is of degree 2 over $\mathbb{Q}$, the degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ is at most 2...*

I understand that $\sqrt{3}$ is of degree 2 over $\mathbb{Q}$ (it has minimal polynomial $x^2 - 3$), but I'm lost as to how this implies $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})] \leq 2$.

I also know that $x^2 - 3 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[x]$, so that the degree of $\sqrt{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is at most 2.  This would give $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})] \leq 2$.  But I can't really see how this would imply $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})] \leq 2$?

Comment: $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)]$ makes no sense, since neither field is contained in the other.

Comment: @BarryCipra Very good point!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your observation that $x^2-3\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)][x]$ is the correct one. The reason it gives what you want is because either $x^2-3$ is irreducible, or it isn't. If it is, then $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)[x]/(x^2-3)$ is a field of degree $2$ over the base field because the ideal is maximal, giving degree $2$. If not, then it factors, and the only way is that it splits into a product of linear factors. But then this means there is already a root in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ so $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ and the degree is $1$. Either way it is at most $2$.

Comment: This is helpful.  Two questions...(1) How does $\langle x^2 - 3 \rangle$ being maximal imply $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[x] / \langle x^2 - 3 \rangle$ is of degree 2?  And (2) How does $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[x] / \langle x^2 - 3 \rangle$ being a field of degree 2 give $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) = 2$?

Comment: @SamY. (1) This has nothing to do with maximality, it is just the usual fact that $F[x]/(p(x))$ is a vector space of dimension $\deg p(x)$ over $F$--the maximality just means that this is a field, rather than only a ring or vector space. (2) Recall if $m(x)$ is irreducible over $F$, then $F[x]/(m(x))\cong F(\alpha)$ for some root, $\alpha$ of $m(x)$. In this case $m(x)=x^2-3$ and $F=\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ hence $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)[x]/(x^2-3)\cong \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)(\sqrt 3)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks!